# error trying to check if youtube video exist in mootools

Tags: mootools, jsonp, youtube-api

i have this code

```
 var x = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/FLE2htv9oxc';
        var myJSONP = new Request.JSONP({
            url: x,
            callbackKey: 'jsoncallback',
            data: ({ partTag: is_youtube }),              
            onRequest: function (url) {
                // a script tag is created with a src attribute equal to url
            },
            onComplete: function (data) {
                // the request was completed.
                alert("ok");
            }
        }).send();
```

and i trying to validate if youtube video exist
i keep getting this error

missing ; before statement
[Break On This Error] ...ount='193' viewCount='19488'/>

arrr.. 
what am i doing wrong 
and is there a way to validate the url in any other way

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell it to use v2 and jsonp. as it stands, it returns xml...

```
var x = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/FLE2htv9oxc?v=2&alt=jsonc';
var myJSONP = new Request.JSONP({
    url: x,
    log: true,
    onRequest: function(url) {
        // a script tag is created with a src attribute equal to url
    },
    onComplete: function(data) {
        // the request was completed.
        console.log(data);
    }
}).send();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZD9Y6/ proof.

---

**references**

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#Video_Feeds

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json.html